# How to change file ownership when chown says "invalid user: ‘–R'"?

Tags: command-line, users, chown, ownership

```bsh
ubuntu64@ubuntu:/$ sudo chown –R hduser:hadoop mongodbdata
chown: invalid user: ‘–R'
```

When I try to change the ownership of the file, I am just getting `invalid user: '-R'` error.

Comment: Related: [useradd/usermod not accepting -c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170710/useradd-usermod-not-accepting-c)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You must have copied the command from a webpage that uses strange formatting. That's not a normal minus, try this instead:

```
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop mongodbdata
```

Specifically, the one I copied from your question is an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash) ([U+2013](http://codepoints.net/U+2013)):

```
$ unicode -s  –
U+2013 EN DASH
UTF-8: e2 80 93  UTF-16BE: 2013  Decimal: &#8211;
–
Category: Pd (Punctuation, Dash)
Bidi: ON (Other Neutrals)
```

Comment: In this context, it's probably more appropriate to call it a hyphen than a minus.

Comment: @Alex I beg to differ. Personally, I prefer _minus_ in this context and _hyphen_ when talking about text. [I am not alone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2212/22222), that is the standard old school UNIX way. Some people do say _dash_ but I've never heard it called a hyphen in this context.

Comment: @terdon Huh. That seems really odd to me, but tradition does count for something. I've only ever used the word minus in math.

Comment: @Alex both _minus_ and _dash_ are used in this context but certainly not [_hyphen_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) which is a different thing altogether.