# Trouble Installing Maya 2020

Tags: 20.04

I'm using this guide https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/installing-maya-2020-ubuntu.html and I am stuck on "sudo systemctl enable adsklicensing –quiet
" of step 7. The response it gives me is "Invalid unit name "–quiet" escaped as "\xe2\x80\x93quiet" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?).
Failed to enable unit: Unit file \xe2\x80\x93quiet.service does not exist.
"

Comment: Closely related: [How to change file ownership when chown says "invalid user: ‘–R'"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604925/how-to-change-file-ownership-when-chown-says-invalid-user-r), [useradd/usermod not accepting -c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170710/useradd-usermod-not-accepting-c) The commands used are different but the issue is the same: a website mangled what should be hyphens (there, one; here, two) into an en-dash. On the other hand, perhaps this should be considered a separate question, since an answer could be posted explaining the message from `systemctl` in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I think it should be "--quiet" not "-quiet"

Comment: This seems to be the solution. More specifically, it seems the page the commands shown in the question were copied from unfortunately turned "--" into "–" (i.e., an [en-dash](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2013)). So it's `--quiet` and neither `-quiet` (what one would run if one manually copied it) nor `–quiet` (what one would run if one used copy and paste).