# How to get Maya AdskLicensingService working on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

Following this [Autodesk tutorial](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/installing-maya-2020-ubuntu.html), I'm running into a road block where enabling Autodesk Licensing Service service fails:

```
systemctl enable adsklicensing –-quiet
Failed to enable unit: Unit file \xe2\x80\x93-quiet.service does not exist.
```

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254154/trouble-installing-maya-2020) quotes the exact same issue, but --quiet renders the same error.

Play by play:

This is OK:

```
sudo apt-get install ./adsklicensing9.2.1.2399_0-1_amd64.deb
```

But this doesn't know about the service:

```
systemctl status adsklicensing
```

So trying the next step, this doesn't exist:

```
/opt/Autodesk/AdskLicensingService --run
```

So I found it in:

```
/opt/Autodesk/AdskLicensing/9.2.1.2399/AdskLicensingService/AdskLicensingService
```

but it just sits there and nothing happens:

```
/opt/Autodesk/AdskLicensing/9.2.1.2399/AdskLicensingService/AdskLicensingService --run
```

So I do the next steps they suggest:

```
sudo getent group adsklic &>/dev/null || sudo groupadd adsklic
sudo id -u adsklic &>/dev/null || sudo useradd -M -r -g adsklic adsklic -d / -s /usr/sbin/nologin  
sudo ln -sf /opt/Autodesk/AdskLicensing/9.2.1.2399/AdskLicensingService/AdskLicensingService /usr/bin/AdskLicensingService
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/systemd/system
sudo cp -f /opt/Autodesk/AdskLicensing/9.2.1.2399/AdskLicensingService/adsklicensing.el7.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/adsklicensing.service
sudo chmod 644 /usr/lib/systemd/system/adsklicensing.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable adsklicensing –quiet
sudo systemctl start adsklicensing
```

But the second last one:

```
sudo systemctl enable adsklicensing –quiet (or --quiet)
```

says:

```
Failed to enable unit: Unit file \xe2\x80\x93quiet.service does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, and you've probably solved it.

I'm experiencing a completely different problem, however I can see that your problem is that you've copied too much of the instructions without checking the end result.

The line "systemctl enable adsklicensing –quiet" contains an invalid "long dash" character, which in hex is represented as "\xe2\x80\x93", replace that with two normal dashes instead and it should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1235032)